# PHP mimetype detection for docx

Tags: php, mime-types

It seams that both mime_content_type and PECL Fileinfo extension fail to detect the correct mime type for docx documents.

Is there any extension or solution that will do this in PHP without creating an ugly hack based on file extension?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php

Answer (score 1):

I've found PHP a bit hit and miss when detecting correct mime types. If you are not confident you are getting the correct results using core PHP functions then you could pass a command to the operating system (if on Linux);

```
$output = exec('file --mime-type [filename]');
list($output, $mimeType) = explode(' ', $output);
```

Another alternative is so check the file extension against a list of known mime types; e.g.

http://snipplr.com/view/1937/

But this depends on having a comprehensive list of mime types, which is not ideal.